# Always fail if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)

Tags: ios, sqlite

This is the code that I have used in `Appdelegate.m` to copy the database

```
- (void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded {

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSError *error;
    NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];

    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];


    if(!success) {

        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"LocalSongs.sqlite"];
        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

        if (!success)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

}
```

And this is used to get the DBPath

```
- (NSString *) getDBPath {


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"LocalSongs.sqlite"];


}
```

This is my playlist Insert method

```
-(NSString *)InsertPlaylist :(NSString *)PlaylistName
{
    NSLog(@"passed");
    NSString *status;


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPath=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"LocalSongs.sqlite"]];

    NSLog(@"Database Path %@",dbPath);

    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;


    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSLog(@"open");

        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO LOCALPLAYLIST (PLAYLISTNAME,getdate()) VALUES (\"%@\")",PlaylistName];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            status=@"Playlist Created";
        }

        else
        {
            status=@"Error occured";
        }


        return status;

    }
}
```

The problem I have is this prepare_v2 is always become notdone. It always execute the else part.

```
if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
```

What is the problem with this? Please help me

Comment: Always check the return value of `sqlite3_prepare_v2`. If it fails, log the result of `sqlite3_errmsg()` to see the problem. Never use string formats to create queries. Make proper use of `sqlite3_bind_xxx` instead.

Comment: What is the `getdate()` function? There is no such thing in SQLite.

Comment: BTW, while I'm glad you solved your issue, it is inadvisable to use `stringWithFormat` to insert values into a SQL statement. Your SQL should probably be something like `INSERT INTO LOCALPLAYLIST (PLAYLISTNAME,MYDATECOLUMN) VALUES (?, datetime())` and then use `sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [PlaylistName UTF8String], -1, NULL)` to bind the value to the `?` placeholder. If the playlist name had some double quotes in it, your existing code would fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an error with your query: you are supposed to put a column name in the place you put `getdate()`, i.e. instead of

```
INSERT INTO LOCALPLAYLIST (PLAYLISTNAME,getdate()) VALUES (\"%@\")
```

you should use something like

```
INSERT INTO LOCALPLAYLIST (PLAYLISTNAME,MYDATECOLUMN) VALUES (\"%@\",getdate())
```

After `sqlite3_prepare_v2` the `statement` pointer is `NULL`?

Compare the return values of `sqlite3_prepare_v2` and `sqlite3_step` with the ones in http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html to get a better insight on what's going wrong

Comment: Thanks for the reply, now I gave it as NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO LOCALPLAYLIST (PLAYLISTNAME,DATETIME) VALUES (\"%@\",getdate())",PlaylistName];But still it same. Why is that